# How can I test load for a chat app built on node.js and socket.io?

Tags: node.js, performance, socket.io, load-testing

Here is the link for a simple chat application with room concept which I'm referring to learn how to create socket.io applications - https://github.com/mcantelon/chatrooms.

I need to test how much load this application takes for socket.io.

How can I test how many connections it serves successfully? Is there any tool or method to achieve this?

Comment: This question may be suitable for sqa.stackoverflow.com but it is off topic on Stackoverflow.